# Trying to import Bootstrap on Next.JS but says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, next.js

I'm trying to import Bootstrap from a Next.js project. The order of my imports are:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

I tried with another syntax...

```
require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

But the result is the same...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
>   jQueryDetection
>   /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js:243:26

I inverted the position of the imports and don't work...

Im in index.js page, and... I have both packages installed

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Will answer if I figure out a fix. EDIT: Got it - answering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that your page is trying to import `bootstrap` whenever this page loads, including when the page is being rendered server-side by the Next.js server (or by the `next export` process). Bootstrap, though, can't run on the server-side because it looks for `window.jquery` as part of its startup process, and `window` is undefined when in the node env.

To fix this, you have to wrap the imports for `bootstrap`, `jquery`, and `popper.js` in a check to ensure they are only imported on the client-side:

```js
// At the top of _app.tsx or your individual page:
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  require("jquery");
  require("popper.js");
  require("bootstrap");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this but with an import call not a require @Zack

Comment: Zack thanks dude you answer inspired to make a similar one like @divin-irakaza asked

Answer (score 0):

Sample _app.tsx based on @Zack 's answer but this one uses imports instead to have totally compliant code

```
// _app.tsx page
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  if (globalThis.window !== undefined) {
    import("jquery").then(() => { import("bootstrap"); });
  }

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also trying to fix this issue but instead I used react-bootstrap and it works fine